# Using a TreeMap with images

Tags: image, silverlight, treemap, seam-carving

For representing most popular artists from [EchoNest API](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/artist.html#top-hottt), I've been trying to set-up [Silverlight Toolkit's TreeMap](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) using images, their TreeItemDefinition.ValueBinding being defined as the area of the image.

While it mostly fills up the space when the image stretch is set to 'Fill' :

[image]

When setting image stretch to 'Uniform' a lot of blank spaces remain :

[image]

On this post, image carving is suggested : [Treemapping with a given aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129221/treemapping-with-a-given-aspect-ratio)

How can I know which images should be carved and at what dimensions they should be carved if possible at all ?

Is this problem *solvable* without human intervention for a good result ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to know which images should be carved and at what dimensions they should be carved. An ok-ish euristic might be to check if the mean energy of an image is > a certain threshold (this can be refined to check only blocks of every image, and combining the result later: if the image has blocks without details/energy, it can be carved, at least in that section).

What i think would be better is to apply seam carving to the already composed image: that will try to carve out the white outlines (adding "artificial" energy to the patches of images might lead to even better results, preserving more the shapes of each image). [This](https://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/papers/retBenchmark.pdf) paper might be of use to check out other image resizing methods too.