# Can I use images as the background rectangles for d3 treemaps?

Tags: d3.js, treemap

Is it possible to make a treemap in d3 with the background of each rectangle be an image? I am looking for something similar to what was done in Silverlight [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618733/using-a-treemap-with-images), but for d3. If it is possible, are there any recommended tutorials that walk through the process of connecting the background to an image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways of using images in SVGs. You probably want to define the image as a pattern and then use it to fill the rectangle. For more information, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image) (the procedure is the same regardless of the element you want to fill).

In D3 code, it would look something like this (simplified).

```
svg.append("defs")
   .append("pattern")
   .attr("id", "bg")
   .append("image")
   .attr("xlink:href", "image.jpg");

svg.append("rect")
   .attr("fill", "url(#bg)");
```

Answer (score 7):

Its important to note, that the image needs to have width, height attributes

```
chart.append("defs")
                  .append('pattern')
                    .attr('id', 'locked2')
                    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
                    .attr('width', 4)
                    .attr('height', 4)
                   .append("image")
                    .attr("xlink:href", "locked.png")
                    .attr('width', 4)
                    .attr('height', 4);
```

Comment: just created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/headwinds/6eu0xnvt/#base) to test and works well!

Answer (score 3):

Using patterns to add an image in a rectangle can make your visualisation quite slow.

You can do something like that instead, this is the code I used for my rectangular nodes into a force layout, I wanted to put rectangles filled by an image as nodes:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node");

node.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 80)
    .attr("height", 120)
    .attr("fill", 'none')
    .attr("stroke", function (d) {
        return colors(d.importance);
    }); 

node.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return d.cover;})
    .attr("x", 2)
    .attr("width", 76)
    .attr("height", 120)
    .on('dblclick', showInfo);
```