# how to add an image to rectangle in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Following is the code:http://pastie.org/8667271
This is how it looks like currently:http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=coj7c&s=5#.UuQe5hA1iWg

Basically its the example code of zoom able Icicle.
I want to replace those rectangles in iccle with image in the rectangle shape.
Any suggestions on how to put image instead of rectangle or within the rectangle?

Thanks.

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033034/can-i-use-images-as-the-background-rectangles-for-d3-treemaps) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, exactly like that. i added that method, but still missing something.http://pastie.org/8667297

Comment: Have another look at the answer to that question. You're using the wrong syntax to set the image pattern as fill.